# How to set TimeToLive on Topic Message?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I'm using a camel route to dispatch message to topic.

```
<route>
    <from uri="activemq:queue:TEST"/>
    <to uri="activemq:topic:TEST"/>
</route>
```

How to set timeToLive propertie to the message send by camel?

Answer (score 1):

Google is your friend, a quick search would lead you to the [Camel JMS component documentation](http://camel.apache.org/jms.html) which shows you the way to accomplish this via the uri options.